# Sturm-Liouville problem with 2nd degree polynomial weight function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for methods of solution for the Sturm-Liuville problem:

$f''(x)=C(Ax^2+Bx+D)f(x)$

in $[a,b]$ with $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and $a,b<\infty$

in literature, but cannot find any book or paper. Any suggestion?
Thank in advance.

Comment: Sturm-Liouville problems come with boundary conditions. Are there some?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I edit my question.

Comment: Are the endpoints actually the same as the coefficients?

Comment: No! Thanks again!

Comment: http://dlmf.nist.gov/12.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality :
$$y''(x)= (Ax^2+Bx+C)y(x)$$
$Ax^2+Bx+C= A(x+\frac{B}{2A})^2+C-\frac{B^2}{4A}$
$$y''(x)=\left( A(x+\frac{B}{2A})^2+C-\frac{B^2}{4A}\right)y(x)$$
Compare to the Parabolic Cylinder ODE :
$$y''(X)=\left( -\frac{1}{4}X^2+\nu+\frac{1}{2}\right)y(x)$$
They become identical with the change : 
$\quad\begin{cases}
X=\frac{B+2Ax}{\sqrt{2}\:A^{3/4}} \\
\nu=\frac{B^2-4AC-4A^{3/2}}{8A^{3/2}}
\end{cases}$

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderDifferentialEquation.html

Thus, the general solution is :
$\quad y(X)=c_1\text{D}_\nu(X)+c_2\text{D}_{-\nu}(iX)\quad$ where $\quad D_\nu(X)\quad$ is the Parabolic Cylinder function.
$$y(x)=c_1\text{D}_\nu\left(\frac{B+2Ax}{\sqrt{2}\:A^{3/4}} \right)+c_2\text{D}_{-\nu}\left(i\frac{B+2Ax}{\sqrt{2}\:A^{3/4}} \right)$$

Conditions : $\quad y(a)=y(b)=0$

In the general case (any $A,B,C,a,b$) $\:\implies\: c_1=c_2=0\:
\text{ . The solution is trivial : }y(x)=0$

For some particular values of $A,B,C,a,b$ , possibly they are an infinity of solutions. They are too many different cases to be commented. Do you have some particular cases which could justify further investigations ?